# Insert image or ad script after 3 posts using the loop

Tags: loop

There are many scripts/hacks out there to insert ads into the middle of the post (after 'x' number of paragraphs), however I haven't found a good enough script that can do the above.

This is the script that comes close,

```
<?php $post_counter=0; ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php require('post.php'); ?>
<?php
$post_counter++;
if ($post_counter == 2 || $post_counter == 3) { ?>
INSERT ADSENSE CODE HERE
<?php } ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Taken from [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-put-adsense-in-the-loop-in-the-indexphp-file). But my index.php uses this instead:

```
<?php
$page_num = $paged;
if ($pagenum='') $pagenum =1;
query_posts('cat=-3&showposts=6&paged='.$page_num); ?>
            <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php get_template_part('includes/index-loop'); ?>
            <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); wp_reset_query(); ?>
            <div class="clear"></div>

        <?php else : ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

I tried putting in the

```
<?php
$post_counter++;
if ($post_counter == 2 || $post_counter == 3) { ?>
INSERT ADSENSE CODE HERE
<?php } ?>
```

before endwhile, but I see a repetition of 'INSERT ADSENSE CODE HERE' twice. Any suggestions?

Comment: "I see a repetition of 'INSERT ADSENSE CODE HERE' twice" - possibly because of the OR in the conditional statement `if ($post_counter == 2 || $post_counter == 3)` ? or do you mean somthing else?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

instead of a post counter, you could use the variable `$wp_query->current_post` - which starts with 0 for the first post in the loop;

for some output after the third post, use for instance this before the line with `endwhile;`:

```
<?php if( $wp_query->current_post == 2 ) { ?>
DO SOMETHING
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: do I need to put in singe post/page tempalte? if yes where exactly in it?

Comment: the code should go into the loop of the index template. detaills depend on your used theme.

Comment: Can we do this randomly in the loop  ?

Comment: @MuhammadRiyaz - generally yes, however, the code would be more complex because you need to get the random value before the loop and then use it instead of the number in the if statement. consider to start your own question to get a detailed answer.

Comment: @Michael - Thanks for reply. I found a solution. 
      <?php $ad_positions = array(2,3,4,5,6); // array of preset possible ad positions
      $numb = $ad_positions[rand(0, count($ad_positions) - 1)]; 
      
  if( $wp_query->current_post == $numb ) { ?>
    DO SOMETHING
    <?php } ?>

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php $ad_positions = array(2,3,4,5,6); // array of preset possible ad positions 
$numb = $ad_positions[rand(0, count($ad_positions) - 1)]; 

if( $wp_query->current_post == $numb ) { ?> 
DO SOMETHING 
<?php } ?>
```

If anybody need to show the ad in **random positions**, above code will help in the wordpress loop. Thank you.