# Add Adsense code in index.php

Tags: php, homepage, frontpage

My wordpress blog homepage has thumbnail gallery.

I want add adsense image ad code to 5,10 place.

Below code from my index

```
   <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
  <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('thumb'); ?>>
```

I found BELOW code from [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/61136/insert-image-or-ad-script-after-3-posts-using-the-loop) (wordpress.stackexchange)

```
  <?php $post_counter=0; ?>
  <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
  <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
  <?php require('post.php'); ?>
  <?php
  $post_counter++;
  if ($post_counter == 2 || $post_counter == 3) { ?>
  INSERT ADSENSE CODE HERE
  <?php } ?>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
```

I have little knowledge in php. I dont know how to modify it. Kindly help me.

Thanks in advance..)

Comment: Have you seen [this solution](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/80202/how-to-put-a-banner-ad-between-post-1-and-post-2-on-homepage-only/80208#80208)?

Comment: I cant see that where is adsense code ad there? and how to add adsense code in my thumb class? Help me..

Comment: You add the adsense code per widget with that solution.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. But i want my adsense code in  <?php post_class('thumb'); ?>>

Comment: I hope that your idea definitely work. But I am newbie for php. So kindly help me. How to register a text widget? Do i add your code end of index.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a slight variation of [my other answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/80208/73).

First we register two new widget areas, *sidebars* in WordPress-speak.

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'wpse_84250_register_ad_widgets' );

function wpse_84250_register_ad_widgets()
{
    // used on the first page of main loop only
    register_sidebar(
        array (
            'name'          => 'Ad Widget 1',
            'id'            => 'ad_widget_1',
            'before_widget' => '<div class="frontpage-ads">',
            'after_widget'  => '</div>'
        )
    );
    register_sidebar(
        array (
            'name'          => 'Ad Widget 2',
            'id'            => 'ad_widget_2',
            'before_widget' => '<div class="frontpage-ads">',
            'after_widget'  => '</div>'
        )
    );
}
```

You get two new sidebars now in `wp-admin/widgets.php`. Add text widgets with your ad code here.

[image]

Then we insert these widgets into the main loop.

1. On `loop_start` we start execution and hook into `the_post` and `loop_end` if we are on the front page.
   You can remove this condition …

   ```
   if ( ! is_front_page() )
       return;
   ```

   … if you want to show the ads on all archive listings.
2. On each call we increment the internal counter `$count` by one. When the counter is equal to 6 we are below the 5th post an call `dynamic_sidebar()` to show the first widget.
3. When the end of the loop was reached *or* we are below the 10th post we show the second widget and remove our callback to save execution time.

Loop code:

```
add_action( 'loop_start', 'wpse_84250_show_ad_widgets' );

function wpse_84250_show_ad_widgets()
{
    static $count = 0;

    if ( ! is_front_page() )
        return;

    if ( 'loop_start' === current_filter() )
        return add_action( 'the_post', __FUNCTION__ )
            && add_action( 'loop_end', __FUNCTION__ );

    $count += 1;

    if ( 6 === $count )
        dynamic_sidebar( 'ad_widget_1' );

    if ( 11 === $count or 'loop_end' === current_filter() ) {
        dynamic_sidebar( 'ad_widget_2' );
        remove_action( 'the_post', __FUNCTION__ );
    }
}
```

You can make a plugin from that code, see: [Where do I put the code snippets I found here or somewhere else on the web?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/72160/where-do-i-put-the-code-snippets-i-found-here-or-somewhere-else-on-the-web)

Comment: Really Thanks...  <?php if( $wp_query->current_post == 2 ) { ?>
DO SOMETHING
<?php } ?> also working nice.

Comment: I have another question here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/84319/adsense-code-in-infinite-scroll if possible. Kindly help me.